# How to define extern variable along with declaration?

Tags: c, c99, extern, gcc-warning, initializer

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable) says:

> The `extern` keyword means "declare without defining". In other words, it is a way to explicitly declare a variable, or to force a declaration without a definition. **It is also possible to explicitly define a variable, i.e. to force a definition. It is done by assigning an initialization value to a variable**.

That means, *an `extern` declaration that initializes the variable serves as a definition for that variable*. So,

```
/* Just for testing purpose only */ 
#include <stdio.h>
extern int y = 0;
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", y);
    return 0;
}
```

should be valid ([compiled in C++11](http://ideone.com/6XstOA)). But when compiled with options `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99` in GCC 4.7.2, produces a warning:

```
[Warning] 'y' initialized and declared 'extern' [enabled by default]
```

which should not. AFAIK,

```
extern int y = 0;
```

is effectively the same as

```
int i = 0;
```

What's going wrong here ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268589/warning-in-extern-declaration) might also help.  Not the accepted answer, but the one by [AndreyT](http://stackoverflow.com/users/187690/andreyt).  Note the last line of the answer in particular: _Just disable this warning in compiler settings (and, please, write a rude letter about it to GCC team)._

Comment: @devnull just write an answer, if you don't want rep then make it community wiki

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour You could help by upvoting the correct answer and downvoting the _not-so-correct_ in the linked question.

Comment: @devnull this does not really look like an exact dup, although they are related.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I didn't say anything at all about being a dup.  The `gcc` bug report was the starting point.  The other answer seemed to substantiate it.  So anything else would seem redundant.

Comment: You're supposed to put `exter y` in another file

Comment: That seems like a *this might not be what was intended by the programmer* type of warning (such as warning for `if(i=5) {...}`) rather than anything wrong with the code as per the language. Other than that, it's a valid C code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All three versions of the standard — ISO/IEC 9899:1990, ISO/IEC 9899:1999 and ISO/IEC 9899:2011 — contain an example in the section with the title **External object definitions** (§6.7.2 of C90, and §6.9.2 of C99 and C11) which shows:

> EXAMPLE 1
>
> ```
> int i1 = 1;        // definition, external linkage
> static int i2 = 2; // definition, internal linkage
> extern int i3 = 3; // definition, external linkage
> int i4;            // tentative definition, external linkage
> static int i5;     // tentative definition, internal linkage
> ```

The example continues, but the `extern int i3 = 3;` line clearly shows that the standard indicates that it should be allowed.  Note, however, that examples in the standard are technically not 'normative' (see the foreword in the standard); they are not a definitive statement of what is and is not allowed.

That said, most people most of the time do not use `extern` and an initializer.

Comment: I was searching section 6.7.9 to find any relevant quote or example.

Answer (score 9):

This code is perfectly valid.

But any compiler is free to issue additional (informative or not) diagnostics:

> (C99, 5.1.1.3p1 fn 8) "Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated."

What a compiler cannot do is not emitting a diagnostic when there is a constraint or syntax violation.

**EDIT:**

As [devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235132/devnull) put in the OP question comments, Joseph Myers from `gcc` team explains in a [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45977) questioning this diagnostic:

> "This is a coding style warning - the code is valid, but extremely 
>   unidiomatic for C since "extern" is generally expected to mean that the 
>   declaration is not providing a definition of the object."

Comment: I think the most relevant part of the GCC bug report is: "This is a coding style warning - the code is valid, but extremely unidiomatic for C since "extern" is generally expected to mean that the declaration is not providing a definition of the object."

Comment: I think it might be worth adding the example (which I quote in my answer) from the C99/C11 standards to the bug report.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour added an edit to cover part of the bug report content

Comment: @ouah you already had my +1 but I appreciate that you added it in.